# What is the correct way to install and run a django project?

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Python and Django and trying to find the correct way to set up a basic Django project to start learning it.

**Following are my Python, Pip, and Django version details -**

[image]

**Commands to find the versions -**

```
python --version

pip --version

python -m django --version
```

**I used the following commands to create a project and a module inside it -**
django-admin startproject djangoCrud
cd djangoCrud/
python manage.py startapp api

**I was able to run the project using the following command -**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Then I read that I will need a virtual environment for further development,
for which I used the following commands to create and run it -

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
```

But when I tried to run the manage.py file after activating the environment,
It throws an error -

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

[image]
But I can run the manage.py without activating the environment

**Can someone please guide me what's wrong and how do I fix this?**

**Tried steps -**

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
. env/bin/activate
pip install Django
django-admin startproject projectNameHere
python manage.py startapp moduleNameHere
python manage.py runserver
```

[image]

**Able to resolve, the correct sequence for those in need -**

```
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ python -m django --version
2.2.4
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (16.7.2)
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
env
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ source env/bin/activate
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
env
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ python -m django --version
/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/bin/python3: No module named django
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ pip install Django
Collecting Django
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/57/66997ca6ef17d2d0f0ebcd860bc6778095ffee04077ca8985928175da358/Django-2.2.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting sqlparse (from Django)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/53/900f7d2a54557c6a37886585a91336520e5539e3ae2423ff1102daf4f3a7/sqlparse-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from Django)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/76/46d697698a143e05f77bec5a526bf4e56a0be61d63425b68f4ba553b51f2/pytz-2019.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, Django
Successfully installed Django-2.2.4 pytz-2019.2 sqlparse-0.3.0
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ python -m django --version
2.2.4
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ django-admin startproject projectNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ld
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
ld: no object files specified
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ l
bash: l: command not found
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
env             projectNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ cd projectNameHere/
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
manage.py       projectNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py startapp moduleNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
manage.py       moduleNameHere  projectNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

August 31, 2019 - 06:48:23
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'projectNameHere.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[31/Aug/2019 06:48:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
^C(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
db.sqlite3      manage.py       moduleNameHere  projectNameHere
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ manage.py makemigrations
bash: manage.py: command not found
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:projectNameHere aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 31, 2019 - 06:49:59
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'projectNameHere.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[31/Aug/2019 06:50:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16348
```

Comment: Did you install Django in your virtual environment? When you are running the commands to show versions you do not have your virtual environment active

Comment: I installed Django before creating the project and the module inside it and then switched to the environment, What is the correct setup flow? I switch to environment first and then create the project and the modules is it?

Comment: @vorujack has the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure `python` and `pip` is intalled. I do propose installing python3.

Then install python django via pip.

then `pip3 install virtualenv`

Create venv with `virtualenv -p python3 <env_name>`

Activate the env with `source <env_name>/bin/activate`

Then, with create a django project with `django-admin startproject <project-name>`

You can then make migrations.

`python3 manage.py makemigrations`

`python3 manage.py migrate`

Once done you can proceed with creating superuser as `python manage.py createsuperuser <username>`

You can have a much described approach via it's documentation https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

PS:- python3 and python2 won't have a difference if python3 is the defautl version as python command will be symlinked to /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Hi, can you have a look at my `Tried Steps` in the question, check if the sequence is correct? I'm getting an error of No such file found added to the question as well

Comment: You have to install django via pip within the venv again,

Comment: As django configs would be unique to your `venv`, it is always best to install venv first and then activate it and install django. Then you can utilize django commands.

Comment: I got a strange issue, It's installing Django after switching to the environment but, still gives me a `No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you try executing `python3` within the env, and show me the output

Comment: The other thing, don't utilize long names for naming directories ;)

Answer (score 4):

when you create a virtualenv you must setup python again.

first install django in virtualenv:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install django
```

also if you have other packages you must install it.

virtualenv is a separate environment and must setup itself.

Comment: So do I need to switch to the environment first and then create the project and the modules?

Comment: You need to activate the environment and then run pip install

Comment: Yes, always create the virtual environment, activate it and just then install all the modules and create the project.

Comment: no any created project can run in virtualenv. but you must install all required packages(in your setup django)

Comment: I added `Tried Steps` to the question, I'm getting a different error now `bash: /Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/projectNameHere/env/bin/python3: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Django inside your virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that help you:
VSCode: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/